# Gitk Yields Blank Unresponsive Gui on OSX Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave, gitk

I recently upgraded to Mojave and now gitk no longer works. When I try to launch gitk I get a blank, unresponsive Wish gui. I suspect it has to do with Mojave's new security requirements on Apple Events but I didn't receive a prompt to grant permissions and I'm not sure how to grant those permissions. Any ideas how to get gitk working again?

I am running macOS 10.14.4. I have git installed via brew and is version 2.21.0

When I launch gitk I don't get any error messages, just a blank gui that is not responsive.

Comment: I my case that happens when running gitk within the PyCharm terminal. In the common OSX (Mojave) terminal, it works.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Mojave?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded to Mojave.